# trying to add an image, a drawing and a circuit at the same time but got wrong

Tags: graphics, circuitikz, rowcolor, qcircuit, drawing

Here, I am trying to draw a circuit and draw an image of how the layers would be looking like and also add an image of the element but they look so ugly. They are so close to each other and not at the same level.

1. would like to put a distance between each other and level them.
2. rename them as 'a', 'b' and 'c'
3. coloured the second drawing and put the layers inside the boxes. I could just draw lines in between and tried '\vline' but it doesn't work as I wanted. [image]

And I think my packages got messed up too, I tried a coloring but packages did not like each other :(
Please, help!

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
\pdfoutput=1
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{cellspace,booktabs}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref !
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{physics}
%\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
 \draw 
(0,0)to [barrier](0,1)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,0)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{tabular}{c} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
     \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
      AlOx\\
      \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}

    \centering % Horizontally center the figure
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{JJCrosssectionFalsecolours} % Include the figure
\caption{a) circuit ... b) A fabr ...}
\label{JJcircuit}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Replace the blank lines with `\hfill` or `\hfil`.  You can use `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]` with tikz/circuitikz.  You can use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to add the `valign=c` option to graphicx.  `\raisebox` for fine adjustment.

Comment: Also, the center environment adds extra vertical space.  Use \centering instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. 
I could use this \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} but it doesn't like valign=c . Maybe I don't know how to add it. This is what I already have \usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

Did not accept \raisebox too

And when I use [baseline=(current bounding box.center)] with \circuitikz their levels completely got weird. All at a different level.

And now they have a very big separation (did it with \hfill). Not that bad but can not label them separately too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my comment:

MikTeX only provides revtex4-2.  I also removed every package not used in the MWE on general principles (most common source of problems is loading too many packages).

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}
%\pdfoutput=1
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{braket}
%\usepackage{cellspace,booktabs}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{layouts}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{physics}
%\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage{url}


%\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref !
%\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
 \draw 
(0,0)to [barrier](0,1)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,0)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\hfil
\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height}{% align geometric center
\begin{tabular}{c} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
     \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
      AlOx\\
      \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{example-image}%{JJCrosssectionFalsecolours} % Include the figure
%\llap{\textcolor{red}{\rule{\columnwidth}{.4pt}}}% show baseline

\caption{a) circuit ... b) A fabr ...}
\label{JJcircuit}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This uses a tabular to align the centers **and** the subcaptions.  There are 6 `\tabcolsep`s used here; two between each column and one at each end.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra,
  superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}
%\pdfoutput=1
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{braket}
%\usepackage{cellspace,booktabs}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{layouts}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{physics}
%\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage{url}


%\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref !
%\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\sbox0{\begin{circuitikz}[american,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
 \draw 
(0,0)to [barrier](0,1)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,0)
(0,1) to [short, -*](0,1);
\end{circuitikz}}% measure width
\sbox1{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height}{% align geometric center
\begin{tabular}{c} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
     \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
      AlOx\\
      \hline
      Al\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}}}%
\sbox2{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{example-image}}%{JJCrosssectionFalsecolours} % Include the figure
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd0-\wd1-\wd2}%
\divide\tabcolsep by 6
\begin{tabular}{p{\wd0} p{\wd1} p{\wd2}}
  \usebox0 & \usebox1 & \usebox2 \\
  \subcaption{} & \subcaption{} & \subcaption{}
\end{tabular}%

\caption{a) circuit ... b) A fabr ...}
\label{JJcircuit}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you so much again, I appreciate you a lot. I did the cleaning with the packages, crazy but I can say 80% was unnecessary thanks to you.
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

Comment: The only thing I am struggling with is that I could not use \subcaption with \circuitikz or \table. 
If you have any references for me then I can check and try. Thanks a lot again and happy new year :)

Comment: The subcaption package provides several options, but \subfloat is probably the one you want.  It measures the size of the image contained and sets the subcaption to the same width.

Comment: \subfloat or \subcaption does not work for me under \circuitikz and \tabular. Thanks for all the help.